# Getting a distinct value, and also a count of that specific value and displaying it in a array

Tags: cakephp

I have a very moderate understanding of cakephp and I haven't been able to solve this problem I have.

For my website people will be able store logs of certain substances they have used. I will later use this data (anonymously) to display charts and statistics back to the website. Right now all my data is stored in a table called "Records" and I have my component/model set up.

All I want to focus on is the field called 'substance' in the table 'records' This field will obviously have the same value repeated multiple times by different members of the website.

Example:

Substance
x
x
y
c
c
c
d

As you can see, x is repeated twice, y, once, c, three times, and d, once.

I need cakePHP to query this table and to display an array as such

```
['x', '2'],
['y', '1'],
['c', '3'],
['d', '1']
```

I assume I will have to use DISTINCT and SUM? But I really have no idea how to do this.

Thanks to whoever can help

Answer (score 0):

The base SQL query that you're looking for is

```sql
SELECT substance, COUNT(*)
  FROM records
 GROUP BY substance
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d07961/1)**

I'm not an expert in cakephp, but it might look something like

```
$result = $this->Record
    ->find('all', 
           array('fields' => array('Record.substance', 'COUNT(*)'),
                 'group'  => array('Record.substance')));
```

Comment: @user2444539 Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Yes i'm trying to solve it right now but can't get it to work. Check out my other reply in this post!

Comment: I attempted your method. When using
            $grouped= implode(',',$grouped);
I get an 'Array to string conversion' error

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($possibleSubstance as $substance){
  $conditions = array(
    'Record.substance' => $substance
  );
  $result[$substance] = $this->Record->find('count', array('conditions' => $conditions));
}
```

$result will be an array ['x'] => #, ['y'] => # etc.

If your possible substances are unknown you can get them first by doing:

```
$fields = 'DISTINCT Record.substance';
$possibleSubstances = $this->find('all', array('fields' => $fields));
```

This will create an array:

```
$possibleSubstances = array(
  (int) 0 => array(
    'Record' => array(
      'substance' => 'x'
    )
  ),
  (int) 1 => array(
    'Record' => array(
      'substance' => 'y'
    )
  ),
);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using virtual fields as documented?
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

```
$this->Record->virtualFields['sum'] = 'COUNT(*)';

// now sum is a field automatically, as well
$grouped = $this->Record->find('all', array(
    'group' => 'Record.substance');
```

to get all the records, or even as list (as requested by you):

```
$grouped = $this->Record->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Record.substance', 'Record.sum'),
    'group' => 'Record.substance');
```

Which will return your array:

```
['x', '2'],
['y', '1'],
['c', '3'],
['d', '1']
```

The cleanest approach.
You can also order it by "substance" or "sum", of course.

Comment: My output; 2,1,4,1,6,1,3,3,7,1 

        $this->Record->virtualFields['sum'] ='COUNT(*)';
        $grouped=$this->Record->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('Record.substance', 'Record.sum'),
        'group' => 'Record.substance'));
        $grouped= implode(',',$grouped);
        $this->set('grouped_set', $grouped);

I then simply echo 'grouped_set' in a view.

Comment: Why do you implode? Just debug() the var.

Comment: The reason is because, I need the data to show in this format:

'x','2',
'y','3'

etc.

If I use debug($var) it display's it like this: 'x' => '2',

The reason I need it in my format is because I need to plug it into google charts